# How to bind visibility based on mouseover/mouseout in a template

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I  am trying to determine a way to show or hide a link based on mouse events. From JSFiddle, I can't seem to get it to work. This is what I have so far:

HTML:

```
<ul multiple="multiple">  
    <!-- ko foreach: list -->   
    <li data-bind="event: {mouseover: $parent.showDelete, mouseout: $parent.hideDelete}">
        <div >
            <span style="vertical-align: center; height: 25px;" 
            data-bind="text: name"></span>
            <a data-bind="visible: $data.deleteVisible" href="#">Remove</a>
        </div>
    </li>        
    <!-- /ko -->
</ul>
<p>
    <button data-bind="click: addItem">Add</button>
    <button data-bind="click: removeItem">Remove</button>
</p>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    var data = [ {name: "Bob"}, {name: "Joe"}, {name: "John"} ]; 
    var viewModel = {
        list: ko.observableArray(data),
        deleteVisible: ko.observable(false), 
        addItem: function() {
            this.list.push({name: "Steve"});                       
        },
        removeItem: function() {
            this.list.pop();
        } ,        
        showDelete: function() {
            this.deleteVisible(true);
        },        
        hideDelete: function() {
            this.deleteVisible(false);
        }        
    };
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);    
});
```

I know the bindings are working correctly, as the data is displayed and the link is hidden. However, when I mouseover or mouseout, I get the follow error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'deleteVisible' 
    viewModel.hideDelete
    (anonymous function)
    jQuery.event.dispatch
    elemData.handle
```

So the error is coming from "hideDelete" within my viewmodel. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making your view models with a self reference?

```
$(function() {

var data = [ {name: "Bob"}, {name: "Joe"}, {name: "John"} ]; 
function viewModel (){
    var self = this; 
    self.list = ko.observableArray(data);
    self.deleteVisible = ko.observable(false);
    self.addItem = function() {
        self.list.push({name: "Steve"});                       
    };
    self.removeItem = function() {
        self.list.pop();
    };        
    self.showDelete = function() {
        self.deleteVisible(true);
    };        
    self.hideDelete = function() {
        self.deleteVisible(false);
    };        
};
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

});